# Screen Brightness Doesn't Change. Gateway NV54

Tags: 11.10, screen, brightness

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to adjust screen brightness on Gateway NV54](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106246/unable-to-adjust-screen-brightness-on-gateway-nv54)

I have a gateway nv54 and the screen brightness does not Change. So I installed indicator brightness but this did not change it.

And the Brightness is the same when the charge is plugged in or unplugged.
What can I do about this?

Comment: This isn't a solution, but as a workaround until you can fix whatever issue your having with your graphics card (which it sees this is), I've found `smartdimmer` to be an effective brightness tool. It's available in the software centre