# How can i make Brightness Control work?

Tags: laptop, brightness

I have Xubuntu 12.04 with latest updates on Toshiba Satellite A210-15K laptop

```
semen@bloknot:~$ uname -a
Linux bloknot 3.2.0-24-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 25 08:43:22 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

...and I can't adjust LCD brightness (. I tried to use fnfx tool:

```
semen@bloknot:~$ fnfx-client
FnFX Client v0.3 (c) 2003, 2004 Timo Hoenig <thoenig@nouse.net>

fatal error: Could not open "/home/semen/.fnfxrc". Please make sure that the default config is accessible.
```

...and xbacklight:

```
semen@bloknot:~$ xbacklight
No outputs have backlight property
```

...and I tried to add acpi_osi=Linux and acpi_backlight=vendor parameters in GRUB config, but nothing happens.

I soppose .fnfxrc file must be available after installation or first fnfx demon lauch. Isn't it?

```
semen@bloknot:~$ cat /sys/class/backlight/toshiba/brightness
-5
semen@bloknot:~$ cat /sys/class/backlight/toshiba/max_brightness
7
semen@bloknot:~$ echo 6 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/toshiba/brightness
[sudo] password for semen: 
6
...
```

...but brightness is the same.

Help, please.

P.S. Execuse me for my poor English.

UPD. I have spent 2 days to solve this boring problem, but I can't. So. If I wish linux work correctly, I have to choose another distro.

Comment: Try [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/57610/43660) first, so we know it's possible to even adjust the brightness.

Comment: I tried it, but brightness is still at the same level

Comment: That's not too good, but there's another good possibility.  Do you use the default `radeon` driver?  Or did you install the proprietary driver?  You can check by typing `lspci -v` in the terminal and looking for the section heading with VGA in it.  Kernel driver in use will state `radeon` if you are using the default.

Comment: Yes. This laptop is not "fresh" ) and there is default radeon driver only.

Comment: You can try installing `fglrx` proprietary driver, which supports your graphics card, and see if brightness will work then.  I believe you can just `sudo apt-get install fglrx`.  Many people use it and have no problems... but switching graphics drivers can cause major issues.  Please don't do this unless you really are bugged by the brightness issue.

Comment: I suppose `fglrx` driver supports only HD series currently. (I have Radeon X1200) and I also suppose that brightness is depends on `toshiba_acpi` kernel module, not `radeon` or `fglrx`. I tried Gentoo Linux (minimal installation CD) and brightness control worked (There are `toshiba_acpi.ko`, `backlight.ko` and `sparse-keymap.ko` kernel modules and it was possible to change brightness by Fn-F6 and Fn-F7 hotkeys).

Comment: Looks like you know a lot more about this than me... sorry I couldn't be of help.

Answer (score 2):

I have a Toshiba Satelite A100 and for me the following command works:

```
echo 0 | sudo tee  /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function brightness() {
    echo $(echo `cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`$1$2|bc)|sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
}
```

Save that to your ~/.bashrc.

Then type `brightness +10` to increase or `brightness -10` to decrease.
It requires password for sudo though.

Answer (score 0):

Your graphics driver is part of the default installation. To check it and to know which driver is currently in use open a terminal and type this in:

```
sudo lshw -C display
```

Look for a line that says `configuration: driver=i915 latency=0`. If its present then the drivers are enabled. To keep the driver updated you just need to keep your system updated with the Update Manager. To be able to use the brightness buttons you need to add something to your grub configuration file.

Open it with you favorite text editor in a terminal, ie gedit

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Locate the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

and change it to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

Save the file and in a terminal type

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot your computer. Your brightness buttons should now be working as expected.

Source: [Unable to adjust screen brightness on Gateway NV54](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106246/unable-to-adjust-screen-brightness-on-gateway-nv54)